# how to read from xlsm encrypted file?

Tags: java, encryption, apache-poi

I am trying to read data from an xlsm Excel file encrypted with password.
So far non of the methods I found on Apache POI web site nor stack-overflow were successful
here is what I tried so far, and the exception I am getting:

```
    String fileName = "C:\\encryptedExcel.xlsm";
    String password = "passcode!";

        try {
            // XOR/RC4 decryption for xls
            Biff8EncryptionKey.setCurrentUserPassword(password);
            NPOIFSFileSystem fs = new NPOIFSFileSystem(new File(fileName), true);           
            HSSFWorkbook hwb = new HSSFWorkbook(fs.getRoot(), true);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();System.err.println(e);}
        //org.apache.poi.EncryptedDocumentException: The supplied spreadsheet seems to be an Encrypted .xlsx file. It must be decrypted before use by XSSF, it cannot be used by HSSF


        try {
            Biff8EncryptionKey.setCurrentUserPassword(password);            
            Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(OPCPackage.open(fileName,PackageAccess.READ));
            Biff8EncryptionKey.setCurrentUserPassword(null);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();System.err.println(e);}
        //org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.OLE2NotOfficeXmlFileException: The supplied data appears to be in the OLE2 Format. You are calling the part of POI that deals with OOXML (Office Open XML) Documents. You need to call a different part of POI to process this data (eg HSSF instead of XSSF)  

        try {
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileName));
            //if (!bis.markSupported()) {is = new PushbackInputStream(bis, 8);}
            if (POIFSFileSystem.hasPOIFSHeader(bis)) {
                POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem(bis);
                EncryptionInfo info = new EncryptionInfo(fs);
                Decryptor d = Decryptor.getInstance(info);
                d.verifyPassword(password);
                //is = d.getDataStream(fs);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        //throws java.io.IOException: getFileMagic() only operates on streams which support mark(int)
        //fixed by converting to BufferedInputStream
        //then throws org.apache.poi.EncryptedDocumentException: Export Restrictions in place - please install JCE Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy files


        try {
            File input = new File(fileName);
            Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(input, password);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();System.err.println(e);}
        //org.apache.poi.EncryptedDocumentException: Export Restrictions in place - please install JCE Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy files
```

Comment: Why not just make your life easy and use the [WorkbookFactory method that takes a password](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/WorkbookFactory.html#create-java.io.File-java.lang.String-) ?

Comment: I tried that, see last try/catch

Comment: What happens if you do what that exception tells you to do, and install the full crypto support into your Java install?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Promoting a comment to an answer...

Firstly, you should use the [WorkbookFactory.create method which takes a password](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/WorkbookFactory.html#create-java.io.File-java.lang.String-), to have Apache POI do all the hard work of detecting the type and setting up the decryption for you, eg

```
Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(new File("protected.xlsx"),"SecurePassword);
```

Secondly, the key error message in your work so far is this one:

```
org.apache.poi.EncryptedDocumentException: Export Restrictions in place - please install JCE Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy files
```

This is telling you that you have a nobbled / hobbled / deliberately-part-broken JVM installation, which lacks enough crypto support to decryt the file you've got. As the error explains, you need to get the unlimited strength JCE files for your JVM from the JVM provider, and install them, to all your Java install to work with strong enough crypto to match what Excel used

Also, the [Apache POI page on Encryption and Decryption](http://poi.apache.org/encryption.html) may come in handy for you too!

Comment: I guess we should add a link to the [encryption page](http://poi.apache.org/encryption.html) in the exception ... to safe the effort to google for the jce policy files ...